# Get coordinates of a bézier-curve with glut

Tags: opengl, bezier

I want to draw a simple Bézier curve (4 control points) with GLUT in a 3D scene. Now I want to duplicate it, then use quads or polygons to join points from the two curves in order to make a surface.

So to achieve this, I think that I need a way to get some coordinates of the Bézier curve.
How can I get them?

Just to make myself clear, I'm trying to draw a 3D surface based on a Bézier-curve.

Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: This is simply evaluating the Bezier Curve at a specific point and you already have to do that to draw it. I don't see your problem.

Comment: I draw the bézier curve without evaluating it at a specific point by using the function: glMap1f

Comment: And what do you think this function actually does?

Comment: Isn't glMap1f deprecated since OpenGL 3.1? You might want to think of an alternative. Isn't really so hard to implement yourself and then you would easily be able to evaluate it as pmr says.

Comment: Ok, first i will look for an alternative, then i will implement a function that draw the curve myself. Thank all of you.

Comment: I did it, by implementing a function that draws the bézier curve...